# Uniform continuity of a particular function

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Given a sequence $(a_n)$ in a metric space $(X,d)$ with no isolated points, such that $d(a_n, a_m) \geq 3\alpha$ for some $\alpha >0$. Moreover, since $(X,d)$ has no isolated point, each $a_n$ is a limit point of $(X,d)$ and hence for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists $b_n \in X$ such that $0< d(a_n, b_n) < \min\{\frac{1}{n}, \frac{\alpha}{4}\}$.  For each $n$, let $U_n= B(a_n, {\alpha})$, $ A_n = \{a_n\} \cup (\overline{U}_n -U_n)$, and define $f:(X,d) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by
$$f(x)= \left \{\begin{array}{lll}
                  \frac{d(x,A_n)}{n[d(x, A_n)+d(x, b_n)]}    & : & x \in \overline{U}_n \\
                  0     & :&  else
                  \end{array}\right\}$$
Now I need to prove that $f$ is uniformly continuous. 
I took $0<\epsilon <1$, fix $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{N} < \epsilon$ and chose $\delta< \min\{\frac{\epsilon \alpha}{4}, \epsilon d(A_1, b_1), 2\epsilon d(A_2, b_2) ...,(N-1) \epsilon d(A_{N-1}, b_{N-1}) \}$. Let $d(x,y) < \delta$. I am not able to prove that $f(x)< \epsilon$ for following case: $x \in U_n$ for $n < N$ and $y \not\in \overline{U}_m$ for every $m$. Please advice. Thank you